# Keywords to Sentences using Neural Networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, lstm, keras

I have to develop a model that takes keywords as input sequence and predict complete sentences as output sequence.

For example:

```
[after tyrant took country citizens abjure political beliefs] => [after the tyrant took over the country the citizens had to abjure their political beliefs]
```

First part is the input sequence and second is the output sequence. I have a dataset of almost 70000 pairs like this.

I have tried the [Seq2Seq](https://google.github.io/seq2seq/) model with Attention. The model training goes relatively well but it fails to learn the pattern.

For Example:

```
src=[after many tests were conducted it was discovered that he carried
     the antigen for a genetic disorder]
target=[after many tests conducted discovered carried antigen genetic disorder]
predicted=[the i i i i i]
```

'src' is the test set example. 'target' is what should it have predicted and 'predicted' is what the model predicted which is completely wrong.
Any solution or guidance will be appreciated, Thanks.

I'm using this as a reference:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-neural-machine-translation-system-keras/

Comment: Maybe post the code you used to run the model

Comment: The best fix is always to produce much more training data.